# New lines with fstream

Tags: line, ifstream

I have to order a lot of data. My professor gave me a .txt file like

```
1 126 17 20 23 32 39 55 68 81 98 111 129 141 151 164 170 182 180 183 187 187 181 186 178    174 175 172 163 159 155 147 140 138 128 122 105 100 99 87 80 66 59 55 48 42 40 33 31 25 25 22 19 19 18 15 15 16 15 16 15 13 13 14 14 14 14 13 13 14 14 13 15 15 14 15 14 14 13 12 13 14 13 14 14 14 13 14 14 13 12 13 13 13 13 14 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 13 13 14 14 14 12 12 13 12 13 11 12 13 12 13 14 12 12 12 11 13 12 13 13 15
2 124 20 34 9 34 51 50 61 76 71 69 95 99 108 103 101 95 89 117 98 107 76 86 66 97 97 80 17 54 45 44 39 40 18 13 29 20 16 15 15 16 14 15 16 16 15 15 14 13 12 14 14 14 12 14 13 12 15 12 12 14 14 11 12 12 14 12 12 13 12 12 13 12 12 12 13 12 13 13 13 12 14 12 12 13 10 12 13 12 13 13 13 12 12 12 13 12 12 13 12 10 15 13 13 12 14 12 12 14 12 12 13 13 13 12 12 12 11 11 13 14 12 12 12 13
```

The first two numbers are the ID, and the energy of a particle. The rest of numbers are other measurements about the particle. I want to count this rest of numbers. But I don't know when I have to stop the while cycle.

Comment: while(!eof){ // Code here }

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream fin("filename");
int i;
while(fin >> i){
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "eof"  function.  Just put it in the wile loop and it's working